# shared element transition to RecycleView not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, shared-element-transition

I have a set of images in parent activity(horizontal linear layout) and I want to make transition for all elements to RecycleView Activity(Grid layout)
Shared element transition not working when I start RecycleView activity, but it works on return to parent activity.

ParentActivity on click method:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChildActivity.class);
Pair[] pairs = new Pair[mContent.getChildCount()];
for(int i = 0; i < mContent.getChildCount(); i++){
    View view = mContent.getChildAt(i);
    view.setTransitionName("trans"+i);
    Pair<View, String> pair = Pair.create(view, view.getTransitionName());
    pairs[i] = pair;
}
ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, pairs);
ActivityCompat.startActivity(this, intent, options.toBundle());
```

RecycleViewAdapter code:

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ViewCompat.setTransitionName(holder.imageView, "trans"+position);
}
```

Comment: Hint: `RecyclerView`itself is also a `View` 
I didn't try shared element transition to a recyclerview so far (only on imageview) but, pretty sure this is not the way. If you want to make a transition of the whole RecyclerView I think you could use only 1 transition (on the Recycler itself) and send data for it to the next activity

Comment: I want to make transition to all elements, not the whole RecyclerView.